# Inserting a table with two key values

Tags: java, sql, insert, postgresql-9.5, dml

I´m using Postgres and java to write files out of a .csv into a db. In my CREATE TABLE stmnts, I have a table which stores two keys. These I want to insert. I now have a subquery but i always get a null value for the ckey, so the syntax must be wrong. The INSERT does not work. ERROR: null value in column "ckey" of relation "gamesin" violates not-null constraint. The other value I get out of a list I created. I´m using a prepared statement. Help appreciated!

```
CREATE TABLE Games(
  Year INT PRIMARY KEY,
  Name VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    StartDate Date NOT NULL,
  EndDate Date NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Cities(
  CKey SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  Name VARCHAR(128) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
  Noc CHAR(3) REFERENCES Countries NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE GamesIn(
  Year INT REFERENCES Games,
  CKey INT REFERENCES Cities,
  PRIMARY KEY(Year, CKey)
);
```

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO gamesin (year, ckey) VALUES (?, (SELECT ckey from cities WHERE cities.name = '\" + name + \"'))";
```

Comment: How is the question related to `java`?

Comment: the program i wrote to ingest and copy the files is written in java... My problem is the ckey was generated so i do not know the values.

Comment: Have you tried to run the subquery against the database? If so: did it return the expected result? If so: have you tried to run the wholel query against the database? If so: did it have the expected effect?

Comment: I gat a syntax error near select and i cant access the list

Comment: Please check that the table `cities` acutally has a column `ckey`. Best would be to [edit] the question and add the schema of `cities`.

Comment: Use a parameter for name as well.